# InfoPath Text Filter for sharepoint 2010 multiple fields

Tags: sharepoint, filter, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I need filter on Info Path Form which can search from multiple fields of Document Set meta Tag?

I tried below things.

1. Create sharepoint filter in infopath for Docment set.
2. Create TextBox that will be free text filter of all the metadata fields of the document set.

Important also that on page load all the Documents and folders of the Dataset will be visible.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried already?  It would help if you would post your code and any errors that you received.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below link. It would help you.

http://sympmarc.com/2011/08/24/using-spservices-with-jqueryuis-autocomplete-function-on-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint/